# Page content is not loading after redirect - React web app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having a problem when trying to redirect using react-router-dom's Redirect.
After the redirect, although the url in the address bar is correct, no content is loaded. It will only load after I refresh the page.

I'm using a customized Route component because I need a isPrivate property to tell when the access to the page is restricted in order to do the redirect.

this is my src/routes/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from './Route';

import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn';

import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={SignIn} />

      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isPrivate />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

this is my src/routes/Route.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function RouteWrapper({
  component: Component,
  isPrivate,
  ...rest
}) {
  const signed = false;

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} component={Component} />;
}
```

and this is src/App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import history from './services/history';
import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also noticed by inspecting the React components tree in the browser that it doesn't load the component tree completely when after the redirect, as in the following images:
[after redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgXzO.png)
and
[after reload or just regular load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcA0w.png)

How can I make the page display correctly after the redirect? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `'react-router-dom'`s `Router` does no replace the need to include `BrowserRouter` in the routes, which is the component that actually syncs the UI and the URL.

in `src/routes/index.js`, enclosing `<Switch>` in `<BrowserRouter>` solves the problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from './Route';

import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn';

import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isPrivate />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```